# Problems when using currentPath() in iOS

Tags: ios, qt

In my program I use commands similar to

```
QDir().mkdir(QDir::currentPath()+"/files");
```

or

```
if(QDir(QDir::currentPath()+"/profiles").exists())
```

and they seem to work fine if I run the from inside

```
test.app/Contents/MacOS/test
```

but if I simply double click test.app it stops working as it should.

in my case it won't list the files inside that directory

```
QDir path(QDir::currentPath()+"/profiles");
QStringList files = path.entryList(QDir::Files);
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Don't use `QDir::currentPath()` as it will break on most platforms, not just iOS (really? iOS?) given it makes assumptions.  Instead use the path derived from `argv[0]` in `main()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider to use [QStandardPaths](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html): it's a very useful class when you have to deal with paths.

```
QString exportedPlaylistLocation = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::MusicLocation);
```

However, you can still use `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` and `QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()`

Comment: QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() fixes the issue, also the suggestion on StandardPaths seems extremely useful.